# Is there a way in R to include weights in a cox regression with Firth's penalized likelihood?

Tags: r, weighted, cox-regression, propensity-score-matching

I am trying to fit a propensity score weighted cox regression model in R. However, one of the treatment groups has zero events, so I also need to use an adjustment method (Firth's penalized likelihood).

I have been using the `coxphf` package just fine to run unweighted models, but there is not an argument that allows for the inclusion of weights in the same was that the regular `coxph` function allows. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585948/is-there-a-way-in-r-to-include-weights-in-a-cox-regression-with-firths-penalize